# Disabling app on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Is it possible using the iPhone SDK, to disable an application unless a pin code is entered which will re-enable it?

Ie: You run an app > it disables the ipod app > if the correct password is entered, it re-enables it?

Is there a function in the SDK to do so / what is it called?

Otherwise how else would be best to go about doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a ransom demand associated with the pin code screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in the iOS SDK.

Comment: Is there a way, whilst this created app is open (and pin code set) it can disable another app from opening?

Comment: As stated in the answer, this cannot be done.  The sandboxed nature of iOS thankfully prevents anything like this from being possible.